# OCR integration to Camera2

Tags: android, android-ndk, tesseract, android-camera2, card.io

I need some advices for my future project. I'm developing OCR project for some ID documents and for this i have already integrated card.io and tess-two and overrided this sources for my project. But my main purpose is about camera. I use Camera1 which is already implemented in card.io source. But when it comes to google developers, they strongly recommend Camera2. When i try to read my documents, i get some problems about focusing, blurred parts and etc. Most part of my algorithms are in Native side. If anyone have already experienced with these technologies, what could you recommend? If i integrate my codes from camera1 to camera2, can i get better results? Thanks for reading my big question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I won't describe you how to use Camera2 API, you should read and try it by your self.

---

**General approach:**

implement **[OnImageAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener.html)** interface in your camera manager class

```
public final class CameraManager implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {

@Override
public synchronized void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
    Image image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
    if (image != null) {
        analyzeFrame(image);
    }
}
```

create **[ImageReader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ImageReader.html)** and initialize before Camera opened

```
private ImageReader imageReader;
private void initialize() {
    //I'm using YUV_420_888 for streaming
    //you may use any supported format from:
    //https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html
    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(PREVIEW_WIDTH, PREVIEW_HEIGHT, ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 1);
                    imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(this, null);
}
```

add surface of your `imageReader` to **[CaptureRequest.Builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.Builder.html)** after camera opened

```
Surface imageSurface = imageReader.getSurface();
//...
previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(imageSurface);
```

handle each frame in `analyzeFrame` method

```
private void analyzeFrame(Image image) {
    //...<-- image processing
    image.close();
}
```

---

> Which Camera api you use?

[Camera2 API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html).

> If i integrate my codes from camera1 to camera2, can i get better
>   results?

short answer is **No**, you'll get the same frames to deal with

> If anyone have already experienced with these technologies, what could
>   you recommend?

I'd recommend you to use **[tess-two](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)**, pay attention on **[OcrRecognizeAsyncTask](https://github.com/rmtheis/android-ocr/blob/master/OCRTest/src/main/java/edu/sfsu/cs/orange/ocr/OcrRecognizeAsyncTask.java)**

Comment: I have already created camera2 preview sample for me. But integrating my source from 1 to 2, will take too much work. Considering native side methods also. That's why i need someone who already tested OCR in Camera2.

Comment: There are no easy way (pass camera object and get results), you should process each preview frame (extract raw data, pass to some native method, get results). **card.io** isn't compatible with my approach, because it starts its own Activity with camera and image processing. My company do native (C++) OCR, i use NDK to process each frame using it.

Comment: Which Camera api you use? Could you answer my last and main question? "If you used both of api's, did you get better results when Optical Reading? "

Comment: First of all, thanks for editing. I'm already using tess-two library. I'll not receive any problem from OcrRecognizeAsyncTask. Because, i initialized tesseract and give boxes in native side. Didn't used their java codes. I used this library, only for prebuilt OCR libs (jpeg,pngt,lept and tess). Anyway, thanks much for details.